# Exact match a string using Regular Expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a string in JavaScript to allow alphanumerics, "(", ")" , and spaces. So test strings are:

```
s1 = "This $h00l*&^ not w0rk342*_(&, <and> always fail" 
s2 = "This should work (ABC1234)"
```

my code:

```
var regX = new RegExp(/A-Za-z0-9\\(\\)\\x20+/);
if(!regX.test(s1)){
    alert("InValid value.");
}
```

But it fails for both the strings.

Also as test() function evaluates the matches in the string and not the whole string
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Can someone please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: As written, your RE will just match strings containing "A-Za-z0-9() +"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9() ]*$/
```

Replace `*` with `+` if you don't want to allow empty string.

`^` and `$` test for beginning and the end of the string respectively.

`*` means repeat 0 or more times. `+` means repeat once or more.

To specify a character class (i.e. a set of character), you need to place the characters inside `[]`.

---

To further shorten the regex:

```
/^[a-z\d() ]*$/i
```

`i` flag will make the regex matches case-insensitively, which remove the needs to specify `A-Z`.

`\d` is the shorthand character class for digits `0-9`. Shorthand character class can also be included inside character class.

Comment: You could shorten it by using the `i` flag and removing the `A-Z` option, as well.